# Win 7 Home Premium 64 bit running Cobian Backup 11 (Gravity)

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-backup

I'm really enjoying Cobian 11, but am fairly new to it. My question is this.

I back up a pretty large folder on a regular basis. I started off by doing a Full backup, and have followed that monthly using differential backups. I was told that, to restore my computer after a crash, I need to copy back the original full backup AND copy back the latest differential over the full.

That's fine. However, over the months there are quite a few large differential backups dated between the original Full one and the latest differential one. To free space on my backup HD, can I every now and then delete the differential backups that lie between the original Full and the latest differential, and just leave the original Full and the latest differential backup on the HD?

Answer (score 0):

Well in theory that makes perfect sense as a differential backup stores all files that have changed compared to the last full backup. You may want to double check cobians definition of a differential just to make sure. Only if it were incremental backup would you need to keep everything in between. You could always do a quick test with a small size test backup.